# Plugin mose doesn't work after suspending laptop

Tags: drivers, suspend, mouse, brightness

First my laptop specs:

- Laptop model: Victus by HP Laptop 16-e0xxx
- RAM:16GB
- AMD Ryzen 7 5800H (16G)
- Graphics card: NVidia RTX 3050
- Current OS Ubuntu 20.04 lts

When I suspend my laptop I'm unable to use the "external mouse".
Also, I don't know if this is related but the brightness of my screen is turned down automatically to the minimum.

If somebody has some suggestions, I would very much appreciate them, this does not prevent me from using my computer but it is annoying.

The mouse does not work if I re-plug it.

Comment: Update UEFI before anything else. It may or may not improve one or both issues. Either way those aren't problems *per se*, the mouse surely works if reconnected and brightness can be increased. Important to understand neither is related to the OS.

Comment: Sometimes, when this happens, you need to unplug and plug the mouse back in after a suspend or after you log in.